# How to list postgresql table data in browser?

Tags: php, postgresql, apache

**Environment:**

- centos6
- php-5.3
- php-pgsql-5.3
- php-pdo-5.3
- httpd-2.2
- postgres-8.4

**Issue:** 
Postgresql table data echoed in shell prompt but not not in browser.

**Php code:**

```
$src="<html>\n<head>,\n<title>db test</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<table>";
$dbc=pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=cricket user=cao password=cri123");
$dmq="select * from batsmen";
$result=pg_query($dbc, $dmq);
while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
$src.="\n<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['name']."</td></tr>";
}
pg_clear_result($result);
pg_close($dbc);
src.="\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>";
```

For example, page source code in shell prompt:

```
<html>
<head><title>db test</title></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Broad man</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Richards</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Sachin</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Lara</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But, page source code in browser:

```
<html>
<head><title>db test</title></head>
<body>
<table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

ie. only static code is sent but no the dynamic table data is sent to the browser.

Comment: You have the </body> and </html> closing tags in the first line.  Nothing of the following is displayed.

Comment: Typo error corrected!

Answer (score 0):

Procedure:
s1: yum install php httpd 
s2: yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib 
s3: yum install php-pgsql 
s4: service postgresql initdb 
systemctl start postgresql 
systemctl enable postgresql 
service postgresql restart 
s5: edit pg_hba.conf 
...
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident 
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident 
...
to 
...
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
...
s6:service postgresql restart
s7:setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1